# plotting structure elements and dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-struct

I'm trying to create a 3D plot in Matlab of a structure element, `Bstruct.scen_1`. In this structure, each row is a year, each column is a distance, and the cell value is a population size (so for example, row 3, column 7 would yield the number of adults in year 3 at 7 km.) I want the X-axis to be the number of columns in `Bstruct.scen_1`, the Y-axis to be the actual value in the cell at (X,Z), and the Z-axis to be the number of rows in `Bstruct.scen_1`.

Conceptually, what I'd like to accomplish is:

`plot3(Bstruct.scen_1(1:num_cols), Bstruct.scen_1(cellvalue), Bstruct.scen_1(1:num_rows))`

I'm struggling with the syntax of structures and would really appreciate help in plotting both the elements and the dimensions of this structure. (I mostly code in R with 'tidy' data.) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a structure field can be any data type. It sounds like the `scen_1` field contains a 2D matrix. The `plot3` function expects an X, Y, and Z coordinate for each data point. In your case, if you're wanting to plot the value of the matrix at each 2D location, using the function `surf` (or `mesh`) might provide a good start:

```
% random data for demonstration
Bstruct.scen_1 = rand(20, 10);

figure;
surf(Bstruct.scen_1);
```